# Jenkins Job DSL does not take parameters

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a Jenkins seed DSL job:

```
job("cronjob/${ACTION}_${ENVRIONMENT}_environment_CRONJOB") {
    scm {
      git('https://git_user@github.com/abc-Data/devops.git','*/develop')
    }
  triggers {
    scm("${SCHEDULE}")
  }
    steps {
      ansiblePlaybook("ansible/scripts/ansible-${ACTION}.yml") {
        inventoryPath("/etc/ansible/hosts")
        credentialsId("usercred")
        extraVars {
            extraVar('environment_name',"${ENVRIONMENT}",false)
        }

      }
    }
}
```

ACTION, ENVIRONMENT and SCHDULE are parameters.

ACTION can have values of  `create` or `remove`, and I have two ansible playbooks `ansible-create.yml` and `ansible-remove.yml`.

When I run the sseed job, I got the following error:

```
ERROR: (unknown source) No signature of method: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.StepContext.ansiblePlaybook() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl, script$_run_closure1$_closure4$_closure5) values: [ansible/scripts/ansible-create.yml, ...]
Finished: FAILURE
```

The `ansiblePlaybook("ansible/scripts/ansible-${ACTION}.yml")` does not work with the variable ACTION.

If I hard code the the script name in `ansiblePlaybook`, the seed job will create a new job.
The other two variables work fine in the DSL script.

What did I miss here?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to cast playbook name parameter to string. `ansiblePlaybook("ansible/scripts/ansible-${ACTION}.yml" as String)`

Comment: Adding the ```as String``` to the code works. Thanks @daggett!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @daggett suggested above, I changed the code as below:

```
job("cronjob/${ACTION}_${ENVRIONMENT}_environment_CRONJOB") {
    scm {
      git('https://git_user@github.com/abc-Data/devops.git','*/develop')
    }
  triggers {
    scm("${SCHEDULE}")
  }
    steps {
      ansiblePlaybook("ansible/scripts/ansible-${ACTION}.yml" as String) {
        inventoryPath("/etc/ansible/hosts")
        credentialsId("usercred")
        extraVars {
            extraVar('environment_name',"${ENVRIONMENT}",false)
        }

      }
    }
}
```

It works as expect and create a new job with the use entered variable values. Thanks to you again @daggett!